Skype icon changed after update
I'm working my way through trying to move family computers away from Windows to Ubuntu Desktop 24.04.
Current issue relates to the Skype icon on the dash.
I installed Skype via the App center and all went well and we had the usual Skype icon on the dash.
At some point Skype updated and the original Skype icon is still there and does take us to Skype although it no longer has the dot to indicate that it is open. But there is now also a cog icon similar to the settings icon that also opens Skype and now indicates that Skype is open.
I have tried removing both from the dash and re-adding from the App menu but the same thing happens.
How can i fix this please?


Although not a complete answer the following does seem to work whereas the stuff after it does not.
If you want to still have a ShowApps Skype icon you need to do the following, otherwise you cans skip the next bit.
You need to copy the desktop icon from the snap to the apt desktop directory which will create two ShowApps icons.
sudo cp /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/skype_skypeforlinux-share.desktop /usr/share/applications
sudo cp /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/skype_skypeforlinux-share.desktop /usr/share/applications

Check they are there: -
sudo ls /usr/share/applications/ | grep skype

Now find the ShowApps icons (there should now be two) and right click on one and select Pin To DASH. It will disappear from the ShowApps and appear in the DASH. This should now work to run Skype although the secondary icon will still appear.

The rest of this doesn't work but I have left it as it shows what I have attempted already.
What has probably happened is that you skype has been converted from an apt to a snap package.
Check with
sudo snap list

If skype is present it is a snap. (I think the apt version has been depreciated.) The icon you have is probably left over from the apt version.
For an inbuilt apt application the icon is stored at one of these locations: -
~/.local/share/applications/
/usr/share/applications/

For a snap package it is stored here
/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications

So, unpin the skype (apt) icon you have. then search for it (see above dirs) and rename name so you don't see it again. Removing this version might just get the snap version working. You might have to restart gnome or the relevant gnome-extension which is easiest done my logging out and in again.
If the snap icon still doesn't show then look for it in the relevant directory (see above). If it is there, there should be an environment variable to point to it.
$XDG_DATA_DIRS should point to /var/lib/snapd/desktop
printenv | grep XDG_DATA_DIRS to see if it is already there.
If it isn't you could add it or just re-install the snap. Theoretically data should be preserved but you should have a complete backup just-in-case.
sudo snap remove skype
sudo snap install skype
sudo snap restore ID

The remove keeps a snapshot of its data (as apposed to purge) and is restored at the end.
To list currently stored snapshots (ID)
sudo snap saved

The ID is the first number. NOTE: saved IDs are auto deleted after 31 days.
Instead of that you could try copying the snap icon to the local directory (see above) and see if that works.
Anyway, I hope this is of some help.

Thanks. I will try this and report back.

I struggled to follow the instructions as I am not very knowledgeable on Linux. I only found Skype mentioned in one of those folders (/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications). There are two files there (skype_skypeforlinux.desktop and skype_skypeforlinux-share.desktop). I could not rename them. This happened on a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04, installing Skype via the App Center. The icon was fine then. Skype then updated itself and this second icon appeared.

Sorry you are having trouble. What you found is sort of what I would expect. When the apt version was removed (assuming you now have a snap version) the DASH has held onto a copy of the icon from the apt icon directory (see above). So if you haven't done it right click on the 'skype' icon on the DASH and select 'unpin' Then, with a logout/login things should start working correct using the snap icon.  To check you have a snap - CTL-ATL T will show a terminal. copy-and-past from the answer 'sudo snap list' into the terminal and press return. Is 'snap' listed?

Skype is listed in sudo snap list.

During investigating this I have broken my rig in the same fashion as your problem. (Probably caused by running Skype (apt) from 20.04 Focal with a common /home to 24.04 which worked with icon and then going back to 24.04. (There are keyring processes to swap from one to another.) I have another rig without a common /home which works in the correct way. Everything in my answer doesn't seem to work in this case. Further when I removed the Skype snap the snapshot failed with an error so I was not able to recover completely. (Error: files remained /home/name/snap )

I have added a work around to the start of the answer.

Thanks for your effort and sorry you have broken your setup.

I found a great alternative to this issue.
Uninstall Skype from the App Center and then install Skype from Flathub.
I know this is not a great solution, but this worked for me.
This link has the setup for Flathub: https://flathub.org/setup/Ubuntu
After these steps are completed you can install Skype from Flathub with the following link: https://flathub.org/apps/com.skype.Client
